# Roundcube webmail change login form

Tags: webmail, roundcube

I am trying to change the label "Username" to "Email Address" on the login form.

When I open /skins/default/templates/login.html it looks like I need to edit:

```
<roundcube:object name="loginform" form="form" />
```

Or is there a language file I need to change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it as soon as I posted this: /program/localization/en_GB/label.inc